# How do I get a value from this array that came out of json_decode?

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to use a few values from this array that comes out of json_decode, but can't get any output from var_dump (which would presumably help me figure out how to access a particular value). I've tried $data[0] also from a suggestion on a similar question.

```
<?PHP
$json = 'callback({"geobytesinternet":"US","geobytescountry":"United States","geobytesregionlocationcode":"USWI","geobytesregion":"Wisconsin","geobytescode":"WI","geobyteslocationcode":"USWILOLA","geobytescity":"Land O Lakes","geobytescityid":"30028","geobytesfqcn":"Land O Lakes, WI, United States","geobyteslatitude":"46.154598","geobyteslongitude":"-89.396896","geobytescapital":"Washington, DC ","geobytestimezone":"-89.3969","geobytesnationalitysingular":"American","geobytespopulation":"278058881","geobytesnationalityplural":"Americans","geobytesmapreference":"North America ","geobytescurrency":"US Dollar","geobytescurrencycode":"USD","geobytestitle":"The United States"});';

$json = str_replace( 'callback(', '', $json);
$json = str_replace( ');', '', $json);
$json = '[' . $json . ']';

$data = json_decode($json);

echo '<br>decoded: ' . $data;

echo '<br><br>var_dump: ' . var_dump($data[0]);

?>
```

Comment: `$json = str_replace( 'callback(', '', $json);
$json = substr($json,  0, -2);

$data = json_decode($json);

var_dump($data);`

Comment: does this come from a service? try to use a url parameter like `&format=json&nojsoncallback=1';` so that you'll get only the json string, then outright decode

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks, but I get no output when I make those changes.

Comment: [demo of those changes](http://3v4l.org/kmOi3)

Comment: @Ghost yes, this is geobytes output. I'm using cURL to retrieve the string, does cURL have a parameter that would help?

Comment: @Lido i'm not refering to cURL parameters, i was referring to the URL query string itself, check geobytes' API and see if they provide the JSON string alone, that doesn't include `callback();` maybe if you add something in the query url string like `&nojsoncallback=1`, they'll just send you plain json string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decoded data is object array so do something like this:

```
$result = $data[0];
echo $result->geobytesinternet;
```

Comment: Wow, this did work, but I'm still getting no output from: echo '<br><br>dumped: ' . var_dump($data[0]);

Comment: remove `echo '<br><br>dumped: '.` just do `var_dump($data[0]);` it will display the output.

Answer (score 0):

You are **almost** there, the function `json_decode()` takes as input **json encoded** string. Your string is not properly json encoded, because of this line `$json = '[' . $json . ']';`.

This is properly encoded json string

`$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';`

`NULL` is returned if the json cannot be decoded or if the encoded data is deeper than the recursion limit. See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

**EDIT:**
So your code should look something like this:

```
<?php
$json = 'callback({"geobytesinternet":"US","geobytescountry":"United States","geobytesregionlocationcode":"USWI","geobytesregion":"Wisconsin","geobytescode":"WI","geobyteslocationcode":"USWILOLA","geobytescity":"Land O Lakes","geobytescityid":"30028","geobytesfqcn":"Land O Lakes, WI, United States","geobyteslatitude":"46.154598","geobyteslongitude":"-89.396896","geobytescapital":"Washington, DC ","geobytestimezone":"-89.3969","geobytesnationalitysingular":"American","geobytespopulation":"278058881","geobytesnationalityplural":"Americans","geobytesmapreference":"North America ","geobytescurrency":"US Dollar","geobytescurrencycode":"USD","geobytestitle":"The United States"});';

//Compact a bit the code, note the ');' replacement
//str_replace() can take an array of arguments, so no need to call the function multiple times
$json = str_replace( array('callback(', ');'), '', $json);
//Get elements in a array
$data = json_decode($json);

//See what's inside the array
var_dump($data);

?>
```

[This](http://codepad.org/bg3lBwhr) is a working fiddle.

Comment: I agree, but without that line that adds square brackets around the string, the code produces no output at all.